# Exibição de frases iniciadas com "<"

Tags: suporte, formatação

Fui editar [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59318/remover-caracteres-de-um-texto) e não consegui de forma alguma escrever em texto uma frase que ficava entre os caracteres de maior e menor. Exemplo:

```
<Frase aqui>
```

No formato de código ela exibe corretamente, mas como fazer com que apareça no texto normalmente? Escrevi mais uma vez entre esses parênteses: (). Provavalmente você só verá se for na edição dessa pergunta. Tentei utilizar o `\` mas também não aconteceu nada: (\). A única solução foi adicionar um espaço entre o caractere e a palavra, dessa forma: (< Frase aqui>).

Comment: Pelo visto o editor aceita entidades HTML: `&lt;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<Assim>, como se faz em HTML ou XML. Código:

> &lt;assim&gt;

Entretanto, para colocar código inline, coloque o trecho entre duas crases simples (`` ` ``), `<assim>`.

Comment: Obrigado! Tinha me esquecido completamente dessa forma. Já sugeri a correção da edição na pergunta citada.